# How to get a button by variable name using a string?

Tags: android, android-layout

My code is like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String a = new String("1,2,3,4,5")

    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    private Button button5;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String[] splited=a.split(",");
                for(String b : splited){
                    (button"b").setBackground(Color.RED); 
                   //This is the part where I get stucked//
                    //I know the code is wrong but I just want to express my idea//
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So,how can I name the button with a changing String b?

The button1 should changing its background color first, then button2, button3, and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only two ways:

1. What Suresh Atta mentioned, because it's not possible to access variable names without reflection.
2. Accessing the button **resources** like this (given the IDs of the buttons in XML are button1, button2 and so on):

   ```
   for (String b : splited){
       findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + b, "id", getPackageName()))
           .setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   }
   ```

Comment: Eclipse said getResources cannot be resolved. I have tried to import but there is no import available. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

No, That is not the way. You cannot do that for a variable name (unless you use `reflection`). Instead of that string take a Button array.

```
private Button[] buttons = {button1,button2.....};
```

Later

```
for(Button b : buttons ){
    b.setBackground(Color.RED);     
}
```

Comment: oh yes a button array!However, if I want to set the order of the button according to the string values(which the string values will change), is there a way to do this?

Comment: @user3947486 Yes. An arraylist is waiting for you :)